# Search in matrix - python

Tags: python, matrix, wordsearch

I need to write a function that will search for words in a matrix. For the moment i'm trying to search line by line to see if the word is there. This is my code:

```
def search(p): 
    w=[]
    for i in p:
        w.append(i)
    s=read_wordsearch() #This is my matrix full of letters
    for line in s: 
        l=[]
        for letter in line:
            l.append(letter)
            if w==l:
                return True
            else:
                pass
```

This code works only if my word begins in the first position of a line.

For example I have this matrix:

```
[[a,f,l,y],[h,e,r,e],[b,n,o,i]]
```

I want to find the word "fly" but can't because my code only works to find words like "here" or "her" because they begin in the first position of a line...

Any form of help, hint, advice would be appreciated. (and sorry if my english is bad...)

Comment: string find after conversion to string?

Comment: Now that you've got a lot of different solutions please pick one and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert each line in the matrix to a string and try to find the search work in it.

```
def search(p):
    s=read_wordsearch()
    for line in s:
        if p in ''.join(line):
            return True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a tip to search within a text for a word.  I think you will be able to extrapolate to your data matrix.

```
 s = "xxxxxxxxxhiddenxxxxxxxxxxx"
 target = "hidden"
 for i in xrange(len(s)-len(target)):
     if s[i:i+len(target)] == target:
         print "Found it at index",i
         break
```

If you want to search for words of all length, if perhaps you had a list of possible solutions:

```
 s = "xxxxxxxxxhiddenxxxtreasurexxxxxxxx"
 targets = ["hidden","treasure"]
 for i in xrange(len(s)-1):
     for j in xrange(i+1,len(s)):
         if s[i:j] in targets:
             print "Found",s[i:j],"at index",
```

Comment: This looks like Python written by a former Java or PHP developer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def search(p): 
  w = ''.join(p)

  s=read_wordsearch() #This is my matrix full of letters
  for line in s: 
    word = ''.join(line)

    if word.find(w) >= 0:
      return True
  return False
```

Edit: there is already lot of string functions available in Python. You just need to use strings to be able to use them.

Answer (score 0):

`join` the characters in the inner lists to create a word and search with `in`.

```
def search(word, data):
    return any(word in ''.join(characters) for characters in data)

data = [['a','f','l','y'], ['h','e','r','e'], ['b','n','o','i']]
if search('fly', data):
     print('found')
```

`data` contains the matrix, `characters` is the name of each individual inner list. `any` will stop after it has found the first match (short circuit).